# Eclipse deleted files

Tags: eclipse, restore, recovery

Eclipse deleted my personal files.
I created a java project directly in my Desktop yes in the Desktop folder.
I judged that the project won't work so i decided to delete it but when deleting it i checked the "Delete project contents on Disk (cannot be undone)". When i saw my error i rushed to the task manager to end the process because i tried to close eclipse and it buged. A couple of Gbs of personal data were deleted in the Desktop.

I installed a couple of Data recovery softwares such as GetDataBack pro, Disk Drill and Recuva in other disk partition ,I ran some scans but i can't find my deleted files.
I need help to restore my data.

Comment: Eclipse should only delete its project folder; but maybe if you had (symbolic) links to other folders, or if you didn't make a folder for your project and told Eclipse that `Desktop` was the project folder, it would have deleted those, too. Which sucks, but recovering accidentally deleted files is not a programming problem, so off-topic here. Also: No backup, no compassion.

Comment: Yes I unfortunately told Eclipse that the folder project is Desktop . I asked chatGPT if Eclipse securely delete data , it told me that it didn't maybe there is a chance.
Thank you